# DataTable unable to get value of checked checkbox from other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

So I have created datatable with customized checkbox. I did not used the plugin of dataTable. I put checkbox manually every td. I am using map function to get data of the checkbox.

Problem here is, I only get values of checkbox on the first page, even tho I checked checkboxes of other pages, I only get the first page. I am using client side datatable btw. Here's my code

```
var values = $("input[name='checkbox_perprod[]']:checked")
          .map(function(){
            dataArr = {
                'product_id'          : $(this).val(),
                'sys_shop'            : $(this).data('sys_shop'),
                'product_name'        : $(this).data('product_name'),
                'product_promo_type'  : 1,
                'product_promo_rate'  : 1,
                'product_orig_price'  : $(this).data('product_price'),
                'product_promo_price' : 0,
                'product_promo_stock' : 0,
                'product_curr_stock'  : $(this).data('product_stock'),
                'product_purch_limit' : 0,
                'product_status'      : 1
            };
            alignProductPromotion(dataArr, counter);
            counter++;
              productArray.push(dataArr);
            }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out other way to solve my problem. I just created separate function to save and delete value of checkbox. I'm storing the data using array and delete it using splice when i uncheck the checkbox. Here's the complete code

```
$('#table-grid-productpromo').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(this.checked) {
            dataArr = {
                    'product_id'          : $(this).val(),
                    'sys_shop'            : $(this).data('sys_shop'),
                    'product_name'        : $(this).data('product_name'),
                    'product_promo_type'  : 1,
                    'product_promo_rate'  : 1,
                    'product_orig_price'  : $(this).data('product_price'),
                    'product_promo_price' : 0,
                    'product_promo_stock' : 0,
                    'product_curr_stock'  : $(this).data('product_stock'),
                    'product_purch_limit' : 0,
                    'product_status'      : 1
                };
            addProdArr.push(dataArr);   // record the value of the checkbox to valArray
        } else {
            var index = addProdArr.findIndex(p => p.product_id == $(this).val());
            if (index !== -1) {
                addProdArr.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    });
```